# Phonegap + localStorage raising error

Tags: android, cordova

I'm trying to create an app using phonegap and localStorage, it works well on iOS but on Android i'm getting the following error: "sqlite returned: error code = 14, msg = cannot open file at line 27205 of [42537b6056]".

I'm looking for answers (Googling it :) ) but without success.

The code and the stacktrace is below.

Thank you in advance.

```
            // Wait for Cordova to load
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

        function onDeviceReady() {
            customers = {
                "data" : [
                    {
                        "name" : "Myself"
                    }
                ]
            }
            navigator.notification.alert(customers.data[0].name);
            window.localStorage.setItem("customers", JSON.stringify(customers));

            var retrievedCustomers = window.localStorage.getItem("customers");
            c = JSON.parse(retrievedCustomers);
            console.log(c);
            navigator.notification.alert(c.data[0].name);

        }
```

Stacktrace:

```
08-21 14:49:05.063: D/DroidGap(11816): DroidGap.onCreate()
08-21 14:49:05.223: D/CordovaWebView(11816): Origin to allow: http://127.0.0.1*
08-21 14:49:05.223: I/CordovaLog(11816): Found log level DEBUG
08-21 14:49:05.223: I/CordovaLog(11816): Changing log level to DEBUG(3)
08-21 14:49:05.223: I/CordovaLog(11816): Found preference for useBrowserHistory=false
08-21 14:49:05.223: D/CordovaLog(11816): Found preference for useBrowserHistory=false
08-21 14:49:05.233: D/DroidGap(11816): DroidGap.init()
08-21 14:49:05.253: D/CordovaWebView(11816): >>> loadUrl(file:///android_asset/www/index.html)
08-21 14:49:05.253: D/PluginManager(11816): init()
08-21 14:49:05.263: D/CordovaWebView(11816): >>> loadUrlNow()
08-21 14:49:05.273: D/SoftKeyboardDetect(11816): Ignore this event
08-21 14:49:05.303: D/SoftKeyboardDetect(11816): Ignore this event
08-21 14:49:05.353: D/SoftKeyboardDetect(11816): Ignore this event
08-21 14:49:05.413: D/DroidGap(11816): onMessage(onPageStarted,file:///android_asset/www/index.html)
08-21 14:49:05.463: D/szipinf(11816): Initializing inflate state
08-21 14:49:05.463: D/szipinf(11816): Initializing zlib to inflate
08-21 14:49:05.513: D/szipinf(11816): Initializing inflate state
08-21 14:49:05.513: D/szipinf(11816): Initializing inflate state
08-21 14:49:05.513: D/szipinf(11816): Initializing zlib to inflate
08-21 14:49:05.583: D/szipinf(11816): Initializing zlib to inflate
08-21 14:49:05.593: D/szipinf(11816): Initializing inflate state
08-21 14:49:05.603: D/szipinf(11816): Initializing zlib to inflate
08-21 14:49:05.813: D/dalvikvm(11816): GC_CONCURRENT freed 134K, 44% free 3390K/6023K, external 0K/0K, paused 4ms+9ms
08-21 14:49:09.143: D/Cordova(11816): onPageFinished(file:///android_asset/www/index.html)
08-21 14:49:09.143: D/CordovaWebView(11816): >>> loadUrlNow()
08-21 14:49:09.143: D/DroidGap(11816): onMessage(onNativeReady,null)
08-21 14:49:09.143: D/DroidGap(11816): onMessage(onPageFinished,file:///android_asset/www/index.html)
08-21 14:49:09.183: I/Database(11816): sqlite returned: error code = 14, msg = cannot open file at line 27205 of [42537b6056]
08-21 14:49:09.253: E/Cordova(11816): Error loading url gap://ready
08-21 14:49:09.253: E/Cordova(11816): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=gap://ready }
08-21 14:49:09.253: E/Cordova(11816):   at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1409)
08-21 14:49:09.253: E/Cordova(11816):   at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1379)
08-21 14:49:09.253: E/Cordova(11816):   at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:2827)
08-21 14:49:09.253: E/Cordova(11816):   at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:2933)
08-21 14:49:09.253: E/Cordova(11816):   at org.apache.cordova.CordovaWebViewClient.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(CordovaWebViewClient.java:187)
08-21 14:49:09.253: E/Cordova(11816):   at android.webkit.CallbackProxy.uiOverrideUrlLoading(CallbackProxy.java:216)
08-21 14:49:09.253: E/Cordova(11816):   at android.webkit.CallbackProxy.handleMessage(CallbackProxy.java:323)
08-21 14:49:09.253: E/Cordova(11816):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-21 14:49:09.253: E/Cordova(11816):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
08-21 14:49:09.253: E/Cordova(11816):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3835)
08-21 14:49:09.253: E/Cordova(11816):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-21 14:49:09.253: E/Cordova(11816):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
08-21 14:49:09.253: E/Cordova(11816):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:847)
08-21 14:49:09.253: E/Cordova(11816):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:605)
08-21 14:49:09.253: E/Cordova(11816):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-21 14:49:11.153: D/DroidGap(11816): onMessage(spinner,stop)
08-21 14:49:14.316: D/CordovaWebView(11816): KeyDown has been triggered on the view
08-21 14:49:14.323: D/CordovaWebView(11816): >>> loadUrlNow()
08-21 14:49:14.783: D/DroidGap(11816): onDestroy()
08-21 14:49:14.783: D/CordovaWebView(11816): >>> loadUrlNow()
08-21 14:49:14.783: D/CordovaWebView(11816): >>> loadUrlNow()
08-21 14:49:14.803: D/DroidGap(11816): onMessage(onPageStarted,about:blank)
08-21 14:49:14.863: D/Cordova(11816): onPageFinished(about:blank)
08-21 14:49:14.863: D/DroidGap(11816): onMessage(onPageFinished,about:blank)
08-21 14:49:14.863: D/DroidGap(11816): onMessage(exit,null)
08-21 14:49:19.843: D/dalvikvm(11816): GC_EXPLICIT freed 350K, 49% free 3118K/6023K, external 0K/0K, paused 61ms
```

Comment: You need to debug it more carefully by adding log messages...One suggestion is to make SET and then GET data in different events...

Comment: Thank you. I did it too and rewrote all line by line and it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you have posted looks fine. I recently created a phonegap app with localstorage option, the only difference I can see is that I used `localStorage.setItem` instead of `window.localStorage.setItem`.

From the error message, you cannot guess what the exact error is. JavaScript is difficult language to debug especially with mobile apps. The approach that works for me mostly is by commenting out lines of code and see if the app works fine without some lines (actually it works the other way, comment out all the code you suspect first and verify the app is working, than start uncommenting lines, 2-3 at a time and see if the app is still working). Once you find out the exact culprit, it is easier to fix.

Comment: Thanks for the tips.
I rewrote line by line and the app worked well.